# How to change the qmake path in to [Qt-dir/bin/].

Tags: qmake

I am trying to compile a Qt application through command line in ubuntu. for me "which qmake " giving /usr/bin. I have given the Qt/bin path in PATH variable. How to change the qmake path in to Qt/bin.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Your question is difficult to understand, so I'll summarize what I think you've asked:

There is a `qmake` installed into `/usr/bin/qmake` and a different `qmake` installed in `/path/to/Qt/bin/qmake`. You want to use the `/path/to/Qt/bin/qmake`. You have added `/path/to/Qt/bin` to your `PATH` environment variable but calling `which qmake` still returns `/usr/bin/qmake`.

There's several possible causes:

- The permissions on `/path/to/Qt/bin/qmake` may not allow you to execute it. Check that `ls -l /path/to/Qt/bin/qmake` shows that you have `x` permission.
- The permissions on any directory above `/path/to/Qt/bin/qmake` may not allow you to *traverse* the directory. If the `ls -l` output from the previous step worked, this is not your problem.
- Make sure `/path/to/Qt/bin` is one of the *first* entries in your `PATH` environment variable. The shell searches directories from the first to the last, in order, to find executables.
- If you added the directory to your `PATH` *after* running `qmake`, the shell will have *hashed* the location of the `qmake` executable internally as a performance optimization. Executables almost never move during a shell session, so this is a useful way to reduce useless system calls. Check the output of `hash -t qmake` to see if this is what happened. Or just execute `hash -r` to force the shell to forget *all* paths. (This has no serious consequences.)

Comment: Yeah.. Thanks for ur detailed explanation.. actually usr/bin path was coming in first in PATH variable. So i changed that by giving like this "PATH=/home/resmi/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4/bin:$PATH" instead of " PATH=$PATH://home/resmi/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4/bin...     Now it is working..

Comment: `fedora 29` /usr/lib64/qt5/bin/qmake -query